# Syntax problem in media query using styled-components

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a small issue, I have 2 ranges of media queries not being read and I think I have a syntax wrong somewhere. I will paste some code

```
const size = {
  mobileS: '320px',
  mobileM: '375px',
  mobileL: '425px',
  ipad: '768px',
  tablet: '1024px',
  laptop: '1024px',
  laptopL: '1330px',
  desktop: '2560px',
};

const device = {
  mobileS: `(max-width:${size.ipad})`,
  ipad: `(min-width: ${size.ipad} and max-width:${size.tablet})`,
  tablet: `(min-width: ${size.tablet} and max-width:${size.laptopL})`,
  desktop: `(min-width: ${size.laptopL})`,
};

export default device;
```

The ipad and tablet screens are not being read and I think that is due to a syntax error in the way I declared the min and max width for the 2 devices.
Please if someone can help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try that. Look at the brackets:

```
ipad: `(min-width: ${size.ipad}) and (max-width:${size.tablet})`,
tablet: `(min-width: ${size.tablet}) and (max-width:${size.laptopL})`,
```